# ExtJS - Synchronous custom language loading?

Tags: extjs, localization

I have a custom language file:

```
Ext.define('DemoApp.util.Resource' {
    singleton: true,

    text: 'English'
});
var R = DemoApp.util.Resource;
```

Now I have another custom language file:

```
Ext.define('DemoApp.util.fr.Resource' {
    override: 'DemoApp.util.Resource',

    text: 'French'
});
```

In Application.js:

```
init: function() {
    var url;

    url = Ext.util.Format.format("locale/util/fr/Resource.js");

    Ext.Loader.loadScript({
        url: url,
        scope: this
    });
},
```

In view I use:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: R.text
}]
```

It loads 'English', but if I put R.text in Ext.Msg.show, it loads 'French'.

Maybe it loads js file after view render. How can I make it load before view render? I tried Ext.apply, it's not working too.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is your code, but in Fiddle this displays first 'English' then 'French':

```
Ext.define('DemoApp.util.Resource', {
    //singleton: true, // makes an error in fiddle
    text: 'English'
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var R = Ext.create('DemoApp.util.Resource');

        alert(R.text);

        Ext.define('DemoApp.util.fr.Resource', {
            override: 'DemoApp.util.Resource',
            text: 'French'
        });

        alert(R.text);
    }
});
```

Remark: pay attention to the coma in the `Ext.define` function.